# Return _id of upserted subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I've looked everywhere and can't figure this out. How can we return the auto-generated _id for an upserted subdocument in MongoDB/Mongoose?

Here's my Schema:

```
var commentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sid : { type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId }, // (story who these comments belong to)
  seq : Number, // bucket #
  cmts : [ {
    tx:String,
    un : String, //username
    u:{ type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId }, //user id
    t:Date
  } ]
});
```

Here's my Query:

```
self.model('Comments').update({
        "sid" : sid,
        "seq" : seq
      }, {
        '$addToSet' : {
          "cmts" : {
            "tx":text,
            "u" : uid,
            "un" : uname,
            "t":new Date(),
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "upsert" : true
      }, function(err, comment) {
        if (err)
          return cb(err);
        console.log("le comments:"+JSON.stringify(comment));
        cb(err, comment);
      });
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!
Henri

Comment: Are you talking about the `_id` for the upserted document itself or the `$addToSet` array element of `cmts`?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose's `update` function will only return `err` and `numAffected` in it's callback so you won't be able to know the _id at that point. The easiest thing to do is just query for it when your update is done.

```
var query = {
    sid: sid,
    seq: seq
};
var data = {
    $addToSet : {
        cmts : {
            tx: text,
            u: uid,
            un: uname,
            t: new Date(),
        }
    }
};
var options = {
    upsert: true,
};

Comments.update(query, data, options, function(err, numAffected) {
    if (err)  ...
    Comments.findOne(query, function(err, comment) {
        if (err) ...
        console.log(comment._id);
        ...
    })
});
```

To know if your comment was inserted or updated you can always do the `findOne` query before the update to see if it exists.

Comment: @cybermach did this help any?